# Condensing an array where some rows differ only by one column (to one with unique rows but more columns)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a long array  (could be pandas or numpy, as convenient) where some rows have the first two columns identical (x-y position), and the third is unique (time), eg:

```
x     y     t
0.    0.    10.
0.    0.    11.
0.    0.    12.
0.    1.    13.
0.    1.    14.
1.    1.    15.
```

Positions are grouped, but there may be 1, 2 or 3 time values listed for each, meaning there may be 1, 2 or 3 columns with identical x and y. The array needs to be reshaped/condensed such that each position has its own row, with min and max values of time - i.e., target is:

```
x     y     t1    t2
0.    0.    10.   12.
0.    1.    13.   14.
1.    1.    15.   inf
```

Is there a simple/elegant way of doing this in pandas or numpy? I've tried loops but they're messy and terribly inefficient, and I've tried using `np.unique`:

```
target_array = np.unique(initial_array[:, 0:2], axis=0)
```

That yields

```
x     y 
0.    0.
0.    1.
1.    1.
```

which is a good start, but then I'm stuck on generating the last two columns.

Comment: Why max of `1  1` is `inf`?

Comment: Right, sorry: because there's only row with position `1   1` and it needs some max; `inf` is just convenient for what I intend to do with this array afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use

```py
out = (df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['t']
       .agg(t1='min', t2='max', c='count')
       .reset_index()
       .pipe(lambda df: df.assign(t2=df['t2'].mask(df['c'].eq(1), np.inf)) )
       .drop(columns='c')
       )
```

```
print(out)

     x    y    t1    t2
0  0.0  0.0  10.0  12.0
1  0.0  1.0  13.0  14.0
2  1.0  1.0  15.0   inf
```